# Evaluate the following integral $\int \frac{2x^2+x\cos x+\sin^{-1}x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I change the integral  $\int \frac{2x^2+x\cos x+\sin^{-1}x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ into 
$$\int \frac{2x^2}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \int \frac{x\cos x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \int \frac{\sin^{-1}x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

and I figure out $\int \frac{2x^2}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\sin^{-1}x + 2x-x\sqrt{1-x^2}$
, however I don't know how to calculate the remaining integrals...

I have tried trigonometric substitution but it seems not working.

Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe $\frac{d}{dx} \sin^{-1}{x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ helps.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int%28+%282*x%5E2%2Bx*cos%28x%29%2Barcsin%28x%29%29%2F%281%2Bsqrt%281-x%5E2%29%29+%29) wouldn't do it.

Comment: It seems as if the integral $\int\frac{x\cos x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$ does not have an elementary closed form. One may be able to find an infinite sum expression for it though.

Answer (score 1):

**PARTIAL ANSWER**

First solve 
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=& \int \frac1{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\\
&=&\int\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2} dx=\\
&=&-\frac1x-\int\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x^2}dx.
\end{eqnarray}
Using $x=\sin t$ we get
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_1 &=&-\frac1x - \int \cot^2 t dt=\\
&=&-\frac1x + \cot t+ t+C=\\
&=&-\frac1x  +\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\arcsin x + C.
\end{eqnarray}

Using this result we can deal with
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_2 &=& \int\frac{\arcsin x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\\
&=& \int\arcsin x d\left(-\frac1x  +\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\arcsin x\right)=\\
&=&-\frac{\arcsin x}x  +\frac{\arcsin x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\arcsin^2 x+\\
& &-  \int\left(-\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}+\frac1x + \frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right) dx=\\
&=&-\frac{\arcsin x}x  +\frac{\arcsin x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\arcsin^2 x+\\
& &-\log |x|-\frac12 \arcsin^2 x+\int\frac1{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx.
\end{eqnarray}
The last term above can be dealt with again with a trigonometric substitution $x=\sin t$, yielding
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_3 &=& \int\frac1{x\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx = \\
&=& \int \csc t dt=\\
&=& -\log |\cot t + \csc t| + C=\\
&=& -\log\left|\frac{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}-\frac1x\right|+C=\\
&=&\log|x| - \log\left|\sqrt{1-x^2}-1\right|+C.
\end{eqnarray}
Thus the last term in you original sum is
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal I_2&=& -\frac{\arcsin x}x  +\frac{\arcsin x\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x}+\\
& &+\frac12 \arcsin^2 x- \log\left|\sqrt{1-x^2}-1\right|+C.
\end{eqnarray}